# Can Ping on an iPod Touch cause DNS issues with other devices on the network?

Tags: itunes, dns, ipod, ping

So I was playing with my iPod Touch recently and I accidentally tapped "Ping" while using the iTunes app. The app then went blank and became stuck in a holding pattern, as if it were trying to download information. It seemed the rest of the iPod was functional, it was only that app that was stuck. I tried restarting the iPod, but that didn't fix it. Then I tried searching the Internet for answers and found that the Internet was apparently down (even though the device was showing a connection). Even my Mac, which uses the same network, was having DNS routing issues, where some websites would load but not others. Finally, after a few minutes, the iTunes app came back to life, and then coincidentally the DNS issues went away.

I'm not really familiar with this new Ping feature. I understand it's vaguely connected with social networking. Does it have some SMS/instant messaging capabilities? Could that mess up my network?

Answer (score 2):

I think something else was causing the issues in your network and the app not wanting to load was just another symptom of those issues, not the cause.